# Sencha touch: how to allow only a-z and A-Z alphabetic in textfield?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, textfield

There is xtype numericfield to allow only number. is there any xtype or way to allow only A-Z and a-z alphabetic in textfield?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it when you define your Model:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
        ],

        validations: [
            {type: 'format', field: 'name', matcher: /^[a-zA-Z]*$/}
        ]
    }
});
```

If you don't use a Model, you can validate data from your text field in your controller like this:

```
if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(field.getValue()))) {
    // Error: only letters are valid
}
```